# Webex Api - How do I exchange the authorization code for the access token using php?

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to fetch the access token by exchanging the authorized_code, but I'm not getting back the access token from the webex api, this is my redirect uri:

```php
<?php 
//retreive authorization code
$code = $_GET['code'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<form id="myForm" action="https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=C4a6e67292f908b0339998b51c57b25a01cb654e09efb426ec42dfa518e6bce44&client_secret=53bdb879dcxxxcbv59cf114116d49712e92f1a6a8a2c95xxxxbvvccd306d4c&code=<?php echo $code; ?>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Fwebex_app%2Fcallback.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
</form>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Required parameters as per the Documentation:
The required parameters are:

Parameter   Value

grant_type   This should be set to "authorization_code"

client_id    Issued when creating your integration

client_secret    Remember this guy? You kept it safe somewhere when creating your integration

code     The authorization code from the previous step

redirect_uri     Must match the one used in the previous step

Complete documentation:
https://developer.webex.com/docs/integrations

Answer (score 0):

Send grant_type, client_id, client_secret & refresh_token in post params (request body / hidden form elements) instead of url params (sending secret codes in url is not secure and hence not supported by webex)